# Can all cardinalities of classes of MK be sets?

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic, cardinals

Is it consistent to add to $\sf MK$, a primitive *total* unary function symbol $\frak c$ standing for the cardinality of a class, axiomatize:

**Hume's Principle :** $\forall X \forall Y: {\frak c}(X) = {\frak c}(Y) \iff ( X \rightarrowtail Y \land Y \rightarrowtail X)$

**Set-hood:** $\forall X: {\frak c}(X) \in V$

Where $V$ is the class of all sets.

The symbol ${\frak c}$ is allowed to be used in comprehension and replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathsf{MK}$ proves that such a function exist, but it's not very interesting. One of the axioms of $\mathsf{MK}$ is the [Axiom of Limitation of Size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_limitation_of_size), which asserts that a class $X$ is a proper class iff it has a bijection with the universe $V$. Consequently, if $X$ and $Y$ are proper classes, then $\mathfrak{c}(X) = \mathfrak{c}(Y)$ always holds. In other words, there is essentially only one "cardinality" for proper classes.

More formally, you can define $\mathfrak{c}$ as follows:
$$
\mathfrak{c}(X) := 
\begin{cases}
|X|, &\text{if $X$ is a set} \\
\{1\}, &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Here $\{1\}$ is arbitrarily chosen, and you can replace it with any definable set which is not a cardinal. Note that the sentence "$X$ is a set" is equivalent to $\exists W[X \in W]$. Therefore, $\mathfrak{c}$ is class-definable, so it can be used in class comprehension and replacement.